# Как сделать так, чтобы появлялось одно уведомление, а через интервал уже другое? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, android-notification

Пытаюсь сделать уведомления в Android Studio. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы сначала появилось одно уведомление, затем, минуя один интервал, появилось уже другое уведомление, и, минуя ещё один интервал, вылезло третье. Здесь пока только 2 уведомления, но второе появляться не хочет. Что я делаю не так? Время менялось несколько раз.

```
public class FirstCompetitionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

AlarmManager alarmManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_competition);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();


            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver1.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);

            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar2.set(2018, 5, 4, 13, 38);

            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver2.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 101, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);

        }
    });
  }
}
```

Ресивер1:

```
public class NotificationReceiver1 extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context, FirstCompetitionActivity.class);
    repeatingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context.getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.i1)
            .setContentTitle("Уведомление")
            .setContentText("Вы приняли участие во всероссийском литературном конкурсе \"Автограф юного писателя\"! " +
                    "Своевременно выполняйте задания. Мы желаем Вам успеха!")
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    createChannelIfNeeded(notificationManager);
    notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());

}

private void createChannelIfNeeded(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

  }
}
```

Ресивер2 практически идентичен:

```
public class NotificationReceiver2 extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ID";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent repeatingIntent = new Intent(context, FirstCompetitionActivity.class);
    repeatingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context.getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.i1)
            .setContentTitle("Уведомление")
            .setContentText("Не забудьте скачать задания!")
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    createChannelIfNeeded(notificationManager);
    notificationManager.notify(101, builder.build());

}

private void createChannelIfNeeded(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }

  }
```

}

Comment: Что пишут в логах?

Comment: Может потому что месяц 5 - это июнь (с точки зрения `Calendar`я). Он считает месяцы с `0`.

Comment: В логах какой-то конкретной ошибки нет, пишется то, что и обычно писалось, когда приложение работало без уведомлений.  А смена месяца на 4, раз календарь работает с 0, тоже не помогла.